# Is there a style type besides text/css?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [style type="text/css" … what else is there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077905/style-type-text-css-what-else-is-there)

I see that when defining a css section it's always

```
<style type="text/css">
</style>
```

Is there anything else it could be? Just curious.

Comment: With HTML5, there also could be nothing instead of `type="text/css"` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML 4 and 5 leave open the possibility of other types, but do not specify any besides "text/css". In practice, I have never encountered a case where anything but "text/css" is used. For this reason, the HTML5 specification made the type attribute optional. If it is omitted, the default type "text/css" is used. See the [style tag specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-style-element) for details:

> The type attribute gives the styling language. If the attribute is
>   present, its value must be a valid MIME type that designates a styling
>   language. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default
>   value for the type attribute, which is used if the attribute is
>   absent, is "text/css". [RFC2318](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/references.html#refsRFC2318)

In HTML 4 documents, the type attribute must be specified. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html) does not limit the values that can be used:

> This attribute specifies the style sheet language of the element's
>   contents and overrides the default style sheet language. The style
>   sheet language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/css").
>   Authors must supply a value for this attribute; there is no default
>   value for this attribute.

In old versions of HTML (<= 4) the type attribute appears to be an attempt to maintain compatibility with the `<link>` method of importing stylesheets, where the `type` is required:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: At least in the current HTML5 CR, the `type` attribute in `link` is optional and purely advisory.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's simply not true that prior to HTML5 `text/css` was the only valid type. There was no default, and no restriction on possible choices, except browser support. In addition, the document you link to does not specify that `text/css` is the only valid type for HTML5.

Comment: Maybe one day there'll be a type="text/scss"

Comment: Updated to include details from the latest version of the HTML5.1 working draft standard and to improve accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is no default for this

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#adef-type-STYLE

> Authors must supply a value for this attribute; there is no default
>   value for this attribute.

There are many options, although `text/css` seems the only reasonable one for style.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-content-type

Comment: Stay updated with [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-style-element.html#attr-style-type)!

Comment: That's still an editor's draft, though, not a recommendation and thus can still change greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Any value would be legal HTML4.01, but the user agent would have to support it. It's much the same thing as specifying a script language - technically you could have anything, in reality only ecmascript/javascript has wide support.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid value is `text/css`

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2318.txt

Comment: [I do not recommend w3schools.](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of "text/css" is the only style type you can have.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html)

[Another Source](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_style.asp)