# In css, why am I unable to place background colored box using div?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to CSS and I'm learning how to create a box but don't understand why my div is not displaying the color blue background? Could you please explain. Thank You.

example:

```
<!--CSS-->
<style>
<style=text/css>
div {height:300px; width:400px; background-color:blue;}
p {height:240px; width:600px; background-color:pink;}
</style>


<!--HTML-->

<body>
<div>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, has dictas vivendo maiestatis in, tota veritus molestie no pri.   Vis no cetero discere pertinax. Mea an iudico fabellas corrumpit. Et justo vivendo mediocritatem nec, dicit aliquip mandamus id per. Vim ne tale menandri. Ne graece iracundia voluptaria his, quis nusquam mea ut, vel cu vivendum corrumpit reformidans. 
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Your style tags are incorrect. Not sure if that is just how you pasted here.

Comment: What is with the misformatted style tags?

Comment: what are you trying to create? you have 2 different width elements p and div with different background colours, generating an ugly output.

Comment: Were the syntax errors in your original code the issue? If so, it shouldn't have been edited by JRulle.

Comment: @j08691: The specific problem was likely `<style=text/css>`, now gone.

Comment: My syntax was wrong. I had used <style=text/css>. And someone here fixed the code in my question. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Your style tags are incorrect for starters.

This is corrected:

```
<style>
div {height:300px; width:400px; background-color:blue;}
p {height:240px; width:600px; background-color:pink;}
</style>
```

*As mentioned by Mouser too. This should be in your head tags

```
<head>
    <style>
    div {height:300px; width:400px; background-color:blue;}
    p {height:240px; width:600px; background-color:pink;}
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw two issues here,

- The div tag was not closed.
- Your style tag was not properly formatted.

I would like to point out that since responding to this the OP has been edited...

so your code should look like this:

```
<html>
<!--CSS-->
<head>
<style type="text/css">

div {
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:blue;
    }
p {
    height:240px;
    width:600px;
    background-color:pink;
    }
</style>
</head>

<!--HTML-->

<body>
<div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, has dictas vivendo maiestatis in, tota veritus molestie no pri.   Vis no cetero discere pertinax. Mea an iudico fabellas corrumpit. Et justo vivendo mediocritatem nec, dicit aliquip mandamus id per. Vim ne tale menandri. Ne graece iracundia voluptaria his, quis nusquam mea ut, vel cu vivendum corrumpit reformidans.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks all. What is the difference in <style type="text/css"> and simply using only <style>

Comment: seems that the type attribute is not required when using HTML5, see the post from George Cummins at this link for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031703/is-there-a-style-type-besides-text-css

Answer (score 1):

You had a tag that looked like this:  `<style=text/css>`.  There was a period of time, after your question had been edited by another, when what was in the question actually worked, which may account for some strange answers.  The result of the working code looks a little strange because the paragraph is wider than the div, but it *does* (or did) work.

I think what you were trying to code is `<style type="text/css">` which is strictly correct.

I've put your code below, with tiny corrections.  It works.

Always remember that the CSS validator at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and the HTML validator at http://validator.w3.org/ are your friends.  When something doesn't work, the *first* thing to do is validate your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stack Overflow Tester</title>
<style type="text/css">
  div {
    height:300px; 
    width:400px; 
    background-color:blue;
  }
  p {
    height:240px; 
    width:600px; 
    background-color:pink;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, has dictas vivendo maiestatis in, tota veritus molestie no pri.   Vis no cetero discere pertinax. Mea an iudico fabellas corrumpit. Et justo vivendo mediocritatem nec, dicit aliquip mandamus id per. Vim ne tale menandri. Ne graece iracundia voluptaria his, quis nusquam mea ut, vel cu vivendum corrumpit reformidans. 
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes! I made changes to it.                                                     div {
    height:300px;
    width:700px;
    background-color:blue;
    }

Comment: @Kendra: Done, and thanks for letting me know.  I would not have noticed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead, remove the background-color from the p selector, decrease the width to 400px. Finally change the div background-color: #0000FF; for a better blue. Hope this helps:)

Answer (score -1):

Please put your style information in the `head` part of your webpage. And remove the unclosed style tag above it. An unclosed style tag prevents the style rules from being parsed. Just as it is with every programming language: If the syntax is incorrect the program will not work or render incorrectly.

Please look into the correct syntax for a webpage. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp

Basic document:

```
<!doctype>
   <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>

        </style>
        <script></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script></script> <!-- can be in head and body, isn't necessary for basic html document. -->
      </body>
   </html>
```

Html elements are written in lowercase.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @hon2a:  Although this answer could have been phrased better (the problem was a *mangled, duplicate* `<style>` tag, not so much an unclosed tag) the answer makes sense and is responsive in the context of the question before the question was edited by another.

Comment: @BobBrown At the time of the review, I judged the answer (in its contemporary form) not to be worthy of separate posting. If it in fact answered the question, the question was bound to get closed as "caused by a simple syntax problem", so my flag didn't do harm either way.

Comment: @hon2a: OK... thanks.  (Yes, it was caused by a syntax error.)