# Eclipse give red lines in hrefs that are properly defined

Tags: html, eclipse, web

[image: Eclipse Web Perspective]

I've create a simple D3.js web project in eclipse as shown above.  I would really like to know how to resolve these red lines as they are very annoying.  The references in the **index.html** file are correct, but Eclipse Luna doesn't seem to understand this.

I'm quite sure this is not a d3 issue as I see this kind of thing when I try set up other web projects with references to style sheets and javascript files.

Everything works as expected in this project.  I just would like to know how to resolve the red lines.  By resolve, I mean having the red lines go away when the references are correct, but show the red lines when they are not.

This may be more than Luna can do at present, but figure it doesn't hurt to ask

Comment: this link might be helpful for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554665/is-type-text-css-mandatory-on-the-link-element

Comment: adding the type='text/css' property to the css links didn't make the red line go away